# I can't save my geometry nodes as presets to reuse in other blend files

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

watched this YouTube tutorial on how to save geometry nodes and I did everything as shown and I get errors when I try to open the presets.

[image]

I pointed the addon to my blender folder and the presets show up under templates when I add to the new geometry node.  I started from scratch 3 times with the same results.  I am not a coder so the doesn't make enough sense to me to remedy it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node presets add-on currently does not support Geometry Nodes trees.

You can find the code there :

https://github.com/blender/blender-addons/blob/master/node_presets.py#L84-L88

```
node_type_string = {
    "ShaderNodeTree": "ShaderNodeGroup",
    "CompositorNodeTree": "CompositorNodeGroup",
    "TextureNodeTree": "TextureNodeGroup",
}[type(node_tree).__name__]
```

It only supports Shader, Compositor and Texture nodes.

You can show your interest in having this feature implemented on [Right Click Select](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/?sorting=hot).

Comment: Thanks.  I feel stupid.  My search was for saving geometry nodes and I was ooking at saving nodes... it was specifically for geometry nodes.  Sorry to have wasted your time.